# read folder tree and convert the tree into an object

Tags: node.js, recursion, fs

I have the following folder structure:

```
+---controllers
|   |   index.js
|   |   
|   +---api
|   |       index.js
|   |       test.js
|   |       
|   \---routes
|       |   index.js
|       |   
|       \---partials
|           |   index.js
|           |   
|           +---bugs
|           +---compatibility
|           +---documentation
|           |       amd.js
|           |       api.js
|           |       jquery.js
|           |       options.js
|           |       usage.js
|           |       
|           \---installation
```

I'm trying to create an object out of the tree that would look like this:

```
{
    api: {
        index: require("index.js"),
        test: require("test.js")
    },
    routes: {
        index: require("index.js"),
        partials: {
            index: require("index.js"),
            bugs: {},
            compatibility: {},
            documentation: {
                amd: require("amd.js"),
                api: require("api.js"),
                jquery: require("jquery.js"),
                options: require("options.js"),
                usage: require("usage.js")
            },
            installation: {}
        }
    }
}
```

I just cannot figure the logic to do it, I've managed only to get an array of the tree with the following code:

```
/**
 * Controllers
 */

var path = require("path"),
    util = require("util"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    wrench = require("wrench");

var controllers = {},
    tree = wrench.readdirSyncRecursive(path.resolve(__dirname, "./")).filter(function (value) {
        return value !== "index.js";
    });


var key,
    i = tree.length - 1;

while (i >= 0) {

    key = tree[i];

    console.log(fs.lstatSync(path.resolve(__dirname, key)).isDirectory(), key.split(path.sep));

    i--;
}

module.exports = controllers;
```

I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to create the object after I start looping the folder tree, but I'm thinking that I could only do it if I have some recursive function ?

**EDIT**:

The reason why I'm trying to do it is because I'm trying to have some kind of dynamic routing for my express application.

In my express application I would have something like:

```
application.get("/api/index", controllers.api.index);
application.get("/api/test", controllers.api.test);
application.get("/", controllers.routes.index);
application.get("/partials/", controllers.routes.partials.index);
application.get("/partials/documentation/amd", controllers.routes.partials.documentation.amd);

...
```

And each of those files would export something similar to:

```
exports.index = function (request, response) {
    return response.render("index");
};
```

Depending on where the file is and maybe with some more logic (in case there is a model that it has to load).

So probably there is a better way of managing dynamic routes than what I'm trying, if so I'm opened for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with a recursive file walker for your case.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filetree = {};

var walkDirectory = function(path, obj) {
  var dir = fs.readdirSync(path);
  for (var i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
    var name = dir[i];
    var target = path + '/' + name;

    var stats = fs.statSync(target);
    if (stats.isFile()) {
      if (name.slice(-3) === '.js') {
        obj[name.slice(0, -3)] = require(target);
      }
    } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      obj[name] = {};
      walkDirectory(target, obj[name]);
    }
  }
};

walkDirectory('./controllers', filetree);
console.log(filetree);
```

The function will scan the directory, and if the file is a script, then it will be loaded. If it is a directory, the function will pass the directory reference to itself and do the same thing again.

Comment: Just tested it and it works just fine :) Just a few more things, is it possible to exclude the root `index.js` file ? The one that is on the same level as the `routes` & `api` ? Because the script that will walk will be in that index file. Also, each file uses `exports.nameOfFunction` to return the export function to the `require`. So all of the objects will have something like `{ api: { test: { test: function () { ... } } } }` can we flatten the last two objects to one, so it ends up like: `{ api: { test: function () { ... } } }` ?

Comment: If you don't want `index.js`, then add `name !== 'index.js'` as a condition to `if (name.slice(-3) === '.js')`. Also, the objects should already be flattened like so, since functions are supposed to be assigned to `module.exports`, not just `exports`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using this module:

[**npm dree**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dree)

A result could be this:

```json
{
  "name": "sample",
  "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample",
  "relativePath": ".",
  "type": "directory",
  "size": "1.79 MB",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend",
      "relativePath": "backend",
      "type": "directory",
      "size": "1.79 MB",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "firebase.json",
          "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend/firebase.json",
          "relativePath": "backend/firebase.json",
          "type": "file",
          "extension": "json",
          "size": "29 B"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "server",
          "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend/server",
          "relativePath": "backend/server",
          "type": "directory",
          "size": "1.79 MB",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "server.ts",
              "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend/server/server.ts",
              "relativePath": "backend/server/server.ts",
              "type": "file",
              "extension": "ts",
              "size": "1.79 MB"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use it to get a structure which contains only the javascript files by using the extensions option. Then you only have to convert the obtained structure to the one you want.

This codesandbox has a solution (see the solution.js file):

[image: Edit Setup Basic Node.js Server]

You can also use the file and directory callback of dree, this is another codesandbox (see the solution.js file):

[image: Edit Setup Basic Node.js Server]